# Property page Format Dialog box variable like OLE_COLOR, stdFont vb6

Tags: vb6, ocx

i m creating ocx for my own text box control 
my question is "how i can set property for data format?"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a Public Property of type `StdFormat.StdDataFormat` (typically named `DataFormat`) you get the rest for free.

Actually making any use of that is a larger question.  You may need an `MSBind.BindingCollection` depending on what is going on in your UserControl.